# Stepsister vs. half-sister

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, société

How do you differentiate between ***half-sister*** (you share one parent) and ***stepsister*** (no blood relation)?

I've seen both translated as ***une demi-sœur***.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with *stepfamily* (me, to start with), the “no blood” relation is due to remariage : one parent remaries with someone already having children — these are them.

Comment: @Mike M. Lin c'est intéressant de voir que le français manque d'un mot pour cela, par contre on fait la différence entre "half-sister" partageant un père "soeurs consanguines", partageant une mère "soeurs utérines" et mêmes soeurs ayant juste partagé le même sein "soeurs de lait": voir http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soeur et [btb](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/juridi/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_u&page=9uK-LaxtfwME.html)

Comment: I don't think there's a word for it. Most of the time, when speaker really wants to insist on the difference, he would probably refer to "the child of my stepfather/stepmother" (no parent shared) or "my stepsister/stepbrother" (1 parent shared). Note that "stepfather"/"beau-père" used here could also mean "the father of my wife" in French, so it might lead to ambiguous discussions if you're married.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use to translate ***stepfamilly*** by *famille par alliance*, so I think you could use something like *une soeur par alliance* to translate ***stepsister***.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A8res_et_s%C5%93urs#Quasi-fr.C3.A8re_et_quasi-s.C5.93ur) seems to agree with the term ***une sœur par alliance***. An alternative given: ***une quasi-sœur***. It also mentions that the term *une demi-sœur* is sometimes used, but is incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

Simply put there is no such thing as a "stepsibling" in French kinship terms. More accurately, if *demi-soeur/frère* is used that way (like we use *beau-père/belle-mère* for both stepparents and in-laws), I do not know of it.

I'm sure people who HAVE stepsiblings (it just so happen that I only have a half-sister and do not know people with stepsiblings) have strategies to discuss it. Myself I usually say I have two sisters, THEN specify one is a half-sister, since I consider both my sisters (from an interpersonal point of view, not a genealogical one).

Answer (score 4):

Most people who share affection with their step-sibling will consider them as their *demi-frère/soeur* and use this term, myself included. However, the problem lies in the bounds within the family.

Answer (score -4):

half-sister : demi-soeur

stepsister : belle-soeur

Comment: *Belle-sœur* is only used for *sisters-in-law*.